# How add div after image block in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, product-images

I want to **add custom div** after image block of **product view page**. In that div I will add custom html like add any text, image etc.

[image]

Anyone have idea how we add custom div by plugin or observer?

Comment: What kind of content you wanted to add there?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI I want to add any html content like `<div>Testing</div>`

Answer (score 3):

copy the `gallery.phtml` file from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view` path to paste `app/design/frontend/theme/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view` path and modifie below code.

```
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <div data-role="loader" class="loading-mask">
        <div class="loader">
            <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
                 alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...') ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Magento 2
</div>
.......
//core code
```

it will appear your code see pic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't want to override files. I want it with plugin or preference. Do you know how we do it with plugin or preference?

Answer (score 2):

**Create a new plugin for getProductDetailsHtml() to add new `<div>` after product**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="plugin_name" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Product" />
</type>
```

**Now create `Product.php`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetProductDetailsHtml($subject, $result)
    {
        $result .= '<div>Your Custom HTML Here</div>';
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will add html after product and price. But thats ok. I already do by this method. Thanks.

Comment: @Prince Patel i try with your above code it works! but not display in after image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin will work here, as the whole block is coming from Javascript.

I tried some different way to get rid of the problem.

you can check my answer here

[Magento 2.2.1:- How to add text in between main image and thumbnail image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204875/magento-2-2-1-how-to-add-text-in-between-main-image-and-thumbnail-image?answertab=votes#tab-top)