# Magento 2.2.1:- How to add text in between main image and thumbnail image

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, magento-2.2.1

[image]

I tried to add text between main image and thumbnail image but i can not add image
I also refer this link:- [How add div after image block in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195541/how-add-div-after-image-block-in-magento-2)

Comment: I also face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not late reply.

I was facing the same issue and I have solved it with Jquery.

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function(){
       var Html = "<p style='text-align: center;'>Enter Your Text Here</p>";
       jQuery('.fotorama__stage').after(Html);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this code but it did not work for me.